# After upgrade to 17.04 Steam won't download updates

Tags: upgrade, steam, dns, 17.04

After my upgrade to 17.04 I found that Steam wouldn't update any games.  Any attempt to update resulted in "content servers unreachable".  The same happened with EVE Online running in wine, it reported that it couldn't find "launcher.eveonline.com".

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install libnss-resolve:i386
```

Allows these applications to once again make dns requests and resolve the needed address.